# Side scroll menu with CSS and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, scroll

I want to create a side scroll menu like [here](http://www.timotheecottier.fr/). What I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="scroll">
<p class="scroll_item" id="1">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="scroll_item" id="2">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="scroll_item" id="3">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="scroll_item" id="4">&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<div id="first"> 1 </div>
<div id="second"> 2 </div>
<div id="third"> 3 </div>
<div id="fourth"> 4 </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .scroll{
        position:fixed;
        height:48%;
        right:4px;
        top:48%
    }


    .scroll_item{
        margin-bottom:10px;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        border: 3px solid #FFF;
    }
    .scroll_item_active{
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        border:3px solid #FFF;
        background-color: #FFF;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

How this should work:
When you click on the `<p>` with the id 3, it will scroll to the div with the id "third", and the box will have the `scroll_item_active` class. On the other hand, if you use the browser's scrollbar, the box's class will still be changed.

I need your help to code the jQuery script.
What I've done:

```
$('#1').onclick(function(.scrollTo('#first');)
$('#2').onclick(function(.scrollTo('#second');)
$('#3').onclick(function(.scrollTo('#third');)
$('#4').onclick(function(.scrollTo('#fourth');)
```

Comment: What error do you get with your code?

Comment: you are missing the selector before `.scrollTo('#fourth');`. Like `$('body, html').scrollTo()` or `$(document)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function navigates to a section with a vertical offset and for smoothness, a time element

```
  function scrollTo(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
    time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
    verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
    element = $(selector);
    offset = element.offset();
    offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, time);
}
```

use this as the click function

```
$('#1').click(function () {
    scrollToElement('#content');
});
```

To switch classes use .addClass ([here](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/))

here is an example, i'm sure you can change it for your needs:

```
$( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );
$( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass noClass" )
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I switch the classes in the conditions I explained in my post?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jP3yw/ - I have posted my scripts on JsFiddle, It's not working for now. Can you take a look, please?

Comment: your click references scrollToElement, your function is called scrollTo. I just updated and it works

Comment: It's working, but only on first 2 divs. I don't get it, the code looks like it's correct. 
EDIT: It's working on every div now, I didn't seen the post with the link. Sorry! Thank you! Can you help me to switch the classes of the boxex when a div is seen?

Comment: I had only updated the first 2 elements with "scrollTo" - the updated link has them all updated. Please look through the code carefully

Comment: I've edited my comment. I didn't see your post with the link.

Comment: Okay, the switch classes stuff is in the answer

Comment: Should I use .on('scroll', handler) to change the class when I scroll to a div?

Comment: I need help with this, if you can. By the way, this is the accepted answer.

Comment: You should open a new question for switching classes, but no, you should be able to add the stuff i put above on to the end of the click function: scrollToElement('#content').addClass("newclass").removeClass("oldclass");